# bash: change names of multiple filles

Tags: bash

within the workdir I have number of files

```
mol0.pdb
mol1.pdb
mol2.pdb
...
mol888.pdb
```

I need to rename this files changing the number +1 for each file in order that it could became like:

```
mol1.pdb
mol2.pdb
mol3.pdb
...
mol889.pdb
```

Could you suggest me some simple solution using bash terminal without possibility to make a script each time and run a loop:

```
for file in *.pdb
do
  # some command to change the number e.g. using i conter with mv
done
```

Comment: I suggest to start with last file.

Comment: This will be easier to do in other languages with better string processing functions.

Comment: Are there any holes in the numbering?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
list=( mol*.pdb )
while IFS= read -r n; do
  mv "mol$n.pdb" "mol$((n + 1)).pdb"
done < <( printf '%s\n' "${list[@]}" | sed 's/mol\(.*\)\.pdb/\1/' | sort -nr )
```

`sort -rn` is here to sort the list of numbers in reverse order such that renaming a file never overwrites another.

Answer (score -1):

here you go:

```
#!/bin/env bash

for file in *.pdb
do
    mv $file "${file%%[[:digit:]]*}$((${file//[!0-9]/}+1))".pdb;
done
```

first pattern remove everything with digits and beyond so we have "file123" becomes "file" now get the file name again and remove the words replacing them with nothing, getting the number, and sum 1, and last we add the extension. Just move one filename to another, and we are done.

Comment: just a question. how to change the name of the directory where the filles will be coppied. I've tried to mv $file "$output"/"${file%%[[:digit:]]*}$((${file//[!0-9]/}+1))".pdb;                   where output is the desired path

Comment: Do not even try this if you care about your files. This will probably overwrite many files because they are not processed in reverse order.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet how they would be overwrrote if were processed in normal order? I do not knew that this could influence.

Comment: Well, if you `mv mol1.pdb mol2.pdb` before `mv mol2.pdb mol3.pdb`, the original content of `mol2.pdb` is lost. So, you **must** `mv mol2.pdb mol3.pdb` before `mv mol1.pdb mol2.pdb`. In the case of the OP you **must** start with the highest number.

Answer (score -1):

Another approach; if there are a lot of files this might be a little faster.

**EDITED**
This line was broken:

```
$: # lst=(file*.xmp); # this is the original assignment that mis-orders the filenames
```

Changing it to this one should work, but gains a bit less less over Renaud's solution, which is probably easier for some to read. YMMV.

```
$:  mapfile -t lst < <( printf "%s\n" file*.xmp | sort -n -k1.5,1 )
$: ndx=${#lst[@]};
$: while [[ -n "${lst[--ndx]}" ]] && ((ndx>=0)); do echo mv "${lst[ndx]}" "newDir/file$((ndx+1)).xmp"; done
mv file9.xmp newDir/file10.xmp
mv file8.xmp newDir/file9.xmp
mv file7.xmp newDir/file8.xmp
mv file6.xmp newDir/file7.xmp
mv file5.xmp newDir/file6.xmp
mv file4.xmp newDir/file5.xmp
mv file3.xmp newDir/file4.xmp
mv file2.xmp newDir/file3.xmp
mv file1.xmp newDir/file2.xmp
mv file0.xmp newDir/file1.xmp
```

Falls apart if there are any gaps in your initial numbering, though.

Comment: This doesn't work because `lst=(file*.xmp)` is not ordered as you think (which you cannot see with your limited example): with a larger set of files `lst[0]=file0.xmp; lst[1]=file1.xmp` but `lst[2]=file10.xmp`...

Comment: Damn, rookie mistake. You're absolutely right. Should have tested a larger sample. Thanks for pointing that out!